# Vitesse starter template stuck on build

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3, vite

I am using [Vitesse](https://github.com/antfu/vitesse) which is a Vuejs starter template for my new dashboard which is `metronic 8` and i am facing a problem when runnuing `pnpm build` is it working when run `dev` but when trying to build the app it showing this

[image]

It keeps stucking on this `rendering chunks (13)` I've tried this [solution](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/5597#issuecomment-988420510)
But it didn't work ..

I've read that `element-plus` is somehow causing the issue when removing it ... and build again i am facing this error [image]

Any idea please?

Comment: Can you share a link to a reproduction of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

1 ) delete node_modules ( rm -rf node_modules ).

2 ) delete package-lock.json ( rm -rf package-lock.json ).

3 ) Removed unused packages in package.json file (Check all the packages to see if there is any where used. If not, remove it in package.json)

4 ) npm install and npm run build.